# Possible Mistake in Hrbacek's "Introduction to Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

In exercise $2.3$ on page $45$, the author writes:

> > $2.3$ Prove that there is a one to one mapping of $N$ onto a proper subset of $N$.

$N$ here denotes the set of all natural numbers. My question is, if you take any finite subset $A\subset N$, wouldn't that imply $N$ is finite as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper subset need not necessarily be finite. For example, consider the proper subset $A=2\mathbb{N}=\{2n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Can you find a one-to-one mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $A$?

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the exercise asks the reader to show that for *any* subset $A\subset N$, there exists a one to one mapping from $N$ to $A$. Clearly $A=\{1\}$ is a proper subset of $N$ so by that exercise, there exists a bijection between $N$ and $\{1\}$ but that is clearly false.

Comment: @Adam that's not what the exercise you posted asks: it just asks that there is a single proper subset $A$ (so not equal to $\mathbb{N}$) such that there is a one-to-one mapping of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $A$.

Comment: @Adam the question, as you phrased it, does not say "any". Like you said, if it were to say "any" it would indeed be wrong, but the phrasing "onto *a* proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: Ah right, I misread it as saying "*any* subset". Thank you.

Comment: @Adam That's because one definition of a set being infinite is that can be mapped bijectively onto *some* proper subset of itself. Finite sets are exactly those sets where you cannot do that. So the exercise shows that $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite by that definition.

Comment: @Adam The sets mentioned by Henno are [Dedekind-infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).